# "cc: Command not found" when compiling a PAM module on Centos

Tags: centos, compiling, radius

I was trying to make a linux server become a radius client. So I downloaded pam_radius. By following the steps from this website : openacs.org/doc/install-pam-radius.html and by following these steps :

```
cd /usr/local/src
wget ftp://ftp.freeradius.org/pub/radius/pam_radius-1.3.16.tar
tar xvf pam_radius-1.3.16
cd pam_radius
make
cp pam_radius_auth.so /lib/security
```

I thought I could install it but I got stuck at "make" I get this error message:

```
[root@zabbix pam_radius-1.4.0]# make
cc -Wall -fPIC -c src/pam_radius_auth.c -o pam_radius_auth.o
make: cc: Command not found
make: *** [pam_radius_auth.o] Error 127
```

I googled this error message and someone said they installed pam-devel. But I get the same message even after installation of pam-devel. What can I do?

Comment: make sure `pam_radius_auth.so` does exist ?

Comment: Check if you have `gcc-c++` installed in your system!

Comment: yes pam_radius_auth.so does exist. I am checking for gcc

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your error message is:

> make: cc: Command not found

which tells you that you are missing the C compiler. As @GAD3R suggests, installing the Development Tools group will correct this. You probably also need the `pam-devel` package.

But, that said: there's really no reason to build pam_radius yourself, as it already exists in EPEL ("Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux"). Find instructions for configuring it [here](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL), and then just `sudo yum install pam_radius`.

Comment: After I did an update and also installed Development Tools I got this error: [root@zabbix ~]# sudo yum install pam_radius
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.wbs.co.za
 * extras: mirror.wbs.co.za
 * updates: mirror.wbs.co.za
No package pam_radius available.
Error: Nothing to do
[root@zabbix ~]#

Comment: After reading a bit more i understand that if I did the make on the pam folder pam_auth.so would have been generated. However it is still not and I since upgrade/update I cannot find that file to move it into the /lib/security folder : ls /etc/pam.d/
chfn  config-util  cvs               ksu    newrole  passwd         remote    runuser    smartcard-auth  smtp.postfix  ssh-keycat  sudo    su-l
chsh  crond        fingerprint-auth  login  other    password-auth  run_init  runuser-l  smtp            sshd          su          sudo-i  system-auth

Comment: On your first comment: you have not enabled EPEL

Answer (score 11):

You need to install the `Development Tools` :

```
sudo yum groupinstall 'Development Tools'
```